# How to prevent divs created when form is submitted from disappearing when form is resubmitted

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have been struggling with this one problem for about 5 days now and I have tried many different things but have not made any progress. Can someone please help me to find a solution?

Here is a video showing what my page does currently
https://i.stack.imgur.com/uTiQV.jpg

What is happening is the user inputs some text into a form which checks for records in a database and creates rows with the info taken from that database. Then when the user ticks the checkbox it will append the row to another div. The problem is that when the user searches another name the rows that have been selected disappear.
I would like for these rows to stay where they are then when the user continues to the next page I would like the info in the selected rows to carry over to the next page.
I have tried many different approaches including cloning the rows, saving the ID as a session variable and attempting to retrieve info for that ID from the database again, and saving the individual names as making the divs from scratch. I am not even sure which approach is the right one let alone how to do it.
I know I have not really given a lot of information but I really don't know what code is important, so if you need any more information just ask.

Comment: Do you mean you want something like a shopping cart  ?  (For shopping cart, if you pick and buy an item, of course you can search other items and buy another item and the previous ones will still be there).

Comment: Yeah something like a shopping cart would do the trick, although I was hoping to have the list of items in the “cart” display on the same page as the search, as opposed to needing to navigate to another page to view it. If there isn’t any solution to this problem I guess I could just continue with the page as it is now but any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: In that case, it can be done like this (1) use a session to store the items selected (2) when user clicks an item after searching, trigger a PHP by ajax to add the item into the session variable (3) on completion of the ajax, update the top DIV by the session variable data. (4) make sure the search page always display in the DIV the updated session variable data, say by a footer script or other method

Comment: I guess the best way would be to store the ID of the selected rows in a session array, but I am not sure if I will be able to create the array, with out it being recreated as a blank array each time the form is resubmitted (if that makes sense)

Comment: Only create the array if it does not exist, else append data to it.